# Beginner to MIPS, why won't it print my third prompt?

Tags: assembly, mips, emulation

I'm trying to write a program in MARS (MIPS Assembler and Runtime Simulator) that will take two integers from the user and then either add or multiply based on what the user chooses to do. Anyways, I haven't gotten too far into the program yet, however I really can't figure out why it won't print my 3rd prompt out. Can you please help me?

```
.data
prompt1: .asciiz "Enter an Integer!"
prompt2: .asciiz "Enter Another Integer!"
prompt3: .asciiz  "Would you like to add or multiply? (+ for add, * for multiply)"
resultout: .asciiz "The result is:"

.text

main:
    la $a0, prompt1
    li $v0, 4
    syscall
    li $v0, 5
    syscall
    add $t0, $v0, $zero

    la $a0, prompt2
    li $v0, 4
    syscall
    li $v0, 5
    syscall
    add $t1, $v0, $zero

    la $a0, prompt3
    li $v0, 12
    syscall
    li $v0, 11
    syscall
    add $t2, $v0, $zero
```

Comment: What is syscall 12? This seems to be the first problem.

Answer (score 1):

To print the prompt and fetch the single character I think you need to load immediate to `$v0` the correct value for the `syscall`. According to the MARS 4.5 Help file, the **Table of Available Services** suggest that your code should be something like this from line 24 on:

```
la $a0, prompt3
li $v0, 4
syscall
li $v0, 12
syscall
```

That is, you want to "print string" whatever is in `prompt3` and then "read character" to get the single character. The first `syscall` you make is 12, which is "read character" so it was waiting for you to input something.

I recommend putting magic numbers like 4 and 12, which represent specific system calls, into the code as constants:

```
.eqv SYS_PRINT_STRING 4
[...]
li $v0, SYS_PRINT_STRING
```

Comment: Don't put magic constants in the `.data` section - that wastes memory!  Use constant definitions like this: `.eqv SYS_PRINT_STRING 4`